# Google Cloud Tools for Visual Studio 2019 no longer deploying to Gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-tools

In the past 2 weeks I have tried installing the Google Cloud Tools extension into Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 without success.  The latest published version in the MS extension store will install just fine, but when launching VS 2019 it gives an extension error and fails to load.  With VS 2022 it loads and you can try to publish to Gcloud however, it immediately says failed to deploy and does not actually try to do anything. It feels like an updated broken extension on either google or Microsoft. I found others on blogs having the same issues lately with the same errors and no suggestions from google.

In Visual Studio 2019 the error is as follows on a New OS install of windows 10 or 11, with a fresh install of VS 2019.:

```
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>CreateInstance failed for package [GoogleCloudExtensionPackage]Source: &apos;mscorlib&apos; Description: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A; at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)&#x000D;&#x000A; at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)&#x000D;&#x000A; at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFromInternal(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)&#x000D;&#x000A; at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName)&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.&#x000D;&#x000A;To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.&#x000D;&#x000A;Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.&#x000D;&#x000A;To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
<guid>{3784FD98-7FCC-40FC-BE3B-B68334735AF2}</guid>
<hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
<errorinfo></errorinfo>
```

On Windows 10/11 with a fresh install of VS 2022, there is no error produced when trying to deploy using the Google Deploy tool. It only says failed to deploy without reason int he log window. Others are reporting this same issue online on forums now as well. It looks like Microsofts latest VS updates or Google Cloud Tool updates have broke soemthing.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue?